# Evaluating variables for constrained Lagrange

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

So if we had the equation bound by a constant such that

$(L(x, y, λ) = 9x^2 - y^2 - λ(9x^2 + y^2 - 81)$

I can determine that

$\frac{∂L}{∂x} = 18x - 18λ$

$\frac{∂L}{∂y} = -2y - 2λ$

$\frac{∂L}{∂λ} = -(9x^2 + y^2 - 81)$

Assuming this is correct, when we equate each partial derivative to $0$ it may be clear that for $f_x, x = 1, λ = 1$ and presumably $y = 0$ but I have an issue with the constraint equation. I understand there are two answers and at first I assumed that $±9 - y = 9$ was the answer as $x = ±1$. However, I realised that there is a $-$ sign and wondered if that still made the application of the square root possible. Also, the $y$ is squared, so doesn't that mean that there is a $±y$ value as well? Is the value of $λ = 0$? Just not sure if I have equated the values correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Lagrange Multiplier method for this problem only if you have not been given a choice. Now coming to your working, there is a mistake.

$L(x, y, λ) = 9x^2 - y^2 - λ(9x^2 + y^2 - 81)$. Equating partial derivatives to zero give you,

$18x - 18\lambda x = 0$

$-2y - 2\lambda y = 0$

$9x^2 + y^2 = 81$

From first, either $x = 0$ or $\lambda = 1 \,$ for $x \ne 0$.

If $\lambda = 1, y = 0$ from the second equation. So $x = \pm3$ given the constraint.

Similarly if $x = 0, y \ne 0,$ (due to constraint). Hence $\lambda = - 1 $ from second equation and $y = \pm 9$ given the constraint.

So you get critical points as $(\pm 3, 0), (0, \pm 9)$.

Comment: Except there are supposed to be four distinct solutions from the equation, so that indicates that there should be 4 values of $x, y, λ$ and $f(x, y)$

Comment: You do not need 4 different values of $\lambda$ for that. You have $2$ different values of $\lambda$ and yes there are $4$ critical points.

Comment: I would also suggest that you sketch them to confirm. You can easily see that the constraint is an ellipse with center at the origin and equation $\frac{x^2}{3^2 } + \frac{y^2}{9^2 } = 1$. The function that we have to minimize / maximize will give you you hyperbola with center at the origin with different lengths of the transverse and conjugate axes. Values $\geq 0$ give you hyperbola with transverse axis as $x-$axis and $\lt 0$ will give you hyperbola with transverse axis as $y-$axis. So you clearly see $4$ points on the curve (ellipse) that minimize / maximize the given function.